# Extracting usernames and userid from E-mail IDs using Ms-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a support of yours, today i got a scenario which i need to do that.

the scenario is email which consists with username and id, needs to split and insert into table in two different columns i.e user id, username.

`ex: ABC123@xyz.com, AAACC2356@mnc.com`

`ABC to be insert in table under username column and 123 to be insert in user id column`

Thanks

Narendra

Comment: All email addresses come in this format?

Comment: Unless there is a distinct separator between username and userid this cannot be directly done in SQL

Comment: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/split-name.aspx

Comment: thanks to all for valuable feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @Email VARCHAR(100)= 'sample12312@test.com'

SET @Email = STUFF(@Email,CHARINDEX('@',@Email),LEN(@Email), '')
SELECT  SUBSTRING(@Email, 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@Email)-1) AS Username,
        SUBSTRING(@Email,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@Email), LEN(@Email)) AS UserID
```

OR

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING(@Email, 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@Email)-1) AS Username,,
        SUBSTRING(STUFF(@Email,CHARINDEX('@',@Email),LEN(@Email), ''), PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@Email), LEN(@Email)) AS UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using few functions:

```
DECLARE @exp VARCHAR(1000) = 'AAACC2356@mnc.com'--'ABC123@xyz.com'

--finds where numbers starts
DECLARE @SplitPoint INT = (SELECT PATINDEX ( '%[0-9]%' , @exp ))
--finds where is @ sign
DECLARE @etaPoint INT = (SELECT PATINDEX ( '%@%' , @exp ))

--gets username
SELECT SUBSTRING(@exp, 0, @SplitPoint)
--gets number
SELECT SUBSTRING(@exp, @SplitPoint, @etaPoint-@SplitPoint)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @X     varchar(100)
Select     @X=    'AAACC2356@mnc.com'

Select     @X=    SubString(@X,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@X),Len(@X))
Select     @X=    SubString(@X,0,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@X))
Select     @X

Declare @Y    varchar(100)
Select     @Y =    'AAACC2356@mnc.com'

Select     @Y=    SubString(@Y,PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%',@Y),Len(@Y))
Select     @Y=    SubString(@Y,0,PATINDEX('%[^A-Z]%',@Y))
Select     @Y
```